# get min value and its related value from an associative array php

Tags: php, arrays, min, associative

i have an array like this

```
$jartot = array(
    0 => array(
        'id_titik' => '1',
        'distance' => '300',
        'name_titik' => 'titik A',
    ),
    1 => array(
        'id_titik' => '2',
        'distance' => '412',
        'name_titik' => 'titik B',
    ),
    2 => array(
        'id_titik' => '3',
        'distance' => '130',
        'name_titik' => 'titik C',
    ),

);
```

i want to get value of min `distance`, and also get its `id_titik`.
i trying use `array_column` to get min value of distance,

```
echo min(array_column($jartot, 'distance'));
```

but how to get its `id_titik` at the same time?

Comment: where is `jarak` in the array?

Comment: already edit it into distance, so jarak = distance in bahasa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might first sort the array using [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) by `distance` and then get the values from the first array:

```
usort($jartot, function($a, $b){
    return $a['distance'] > $b['distance'];
});


echo $jartot[0]['id_titik']; // 3
echo $jartot[0]['distance']; // 130
echo $jartot[0]['name_titik']; // titik C
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/XKqnW)

If there are multiple with the same distance you could use [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to get the lowest value and use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to filter the result where distance equals that value:

```
$min = min(array_column($jartot, 'distance'));
$results = array_filter($jartot, function($x) use ($min){
    return $x['distance'] === $min;
});
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/f4RM4)